# With two nested elements, a click on the lowest does not fire the click event from the top one

Tags: jquery

If got three nested elements:

```
<div class='container' fb-href='someUrl'>
   <span class='someText'>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href='url'>consectetur</a> adipiscing.
   </span>
</div>
```

On the outer div I've got an click event:

```
$('.container').click(function(){
   window.open($(this).attr('fb-href'));
});
```

How can I avoid the event being fired if I click the url within .someText? (Because I off course want to let the user go to the a-link instead of the container-link.)

Comment: Take a look at [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the callback accept an `event` parameter and see what kind of element initiated the event:

```
$('.container').click(function(event){
   if(event.target.tagName != 'A') {
     window.open($(this).attr('fb-href'));
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I avoid the event being fired if I click the url within .someText? (Because I off course want to let the user go to the a-link instead of the container-link.)

Two ways:

1. Hook the `click` event on `.someText` and use `stopPropagation` on the event object.

   ```
   $(".someText").click(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
   });
   ```
2. In the `click` handler on the `.container`, look at `e.target` and ignore the click if it's on a `.someText`.

   ```
   $(".container").click(function(e) {
       if ($(e.target).closest('.someText')[0]) {
           // Don't do anything
       }
   });
   ```

   `e.target` is the actualy element clicked. `closest` finds the first element that matches the selector by looking at the element you give it, then its parent element, etc., etc.

Comment: Wouldn't #1 erroneously disable the popup if the click occurred on the non-anchor part of the span?

Comment: @Jon: Yes it would prevent the popup if on the non-anchor part of the span, but it's not clear from the question whether that's erroneous, as in part of the question it's anything in `.someText`, and in part of the question, it's only the anchor.

Comment: Sure, "erroneous" includes my own interpretation of the question. But in any case, #1 and #2 are not equivalent; IMHO the answer implies they are. A little clarification wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Jon: #1 and #2 are effectively equivalent. Neither checks specifically for the anchor. What makes you think they are different?

Comment: They are effectively equivalent with this markup, but if more stuff is added inside `.someText` later on #1 is going to take the change a lot worse than #2 will. This is IMHO something reasonably likely in the future, so you could say that the difference is that while #1 and #2 are comparably pretty-looking right now, one of them isn't going to age well.

Comment: @Jon: I'm not seeing it. In both cases, regardless of what you add, we'll either do something or not based on whether the click is in (a descendant of) `.someText`. What *specifically* would I add that would be different between the two?

Comment: `<strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum`. Now Lorem and ipsum behave differently, but only with #2. Might be just me, but I don't like this.

Comment: @Jon: No, they don't. Both hit the same handlers, and both behave the same way. Remember that clicks bubble. It doesn't matter whether the user clicks `lorem` or `ipsum`, in both cases in #1, once the click reaches the `.someText` ancestor, propagation is stopped. In #2, `closest` finds `.someText` in both cases. Zero difference.

Comment: True. It definitely looks like I should finally go to bed; sorry for wasting your time with these last comments. Cheers!